# multiple javax.swing.Timer listeners synchronization issue, Java

Tags: java, swing

I have two threads that each sets a timer

`if (threadname.equals("t1")) timer = new javax.swing.Timer(4000,new TimerListener());
 else timer = new javax.swing.Timer(4000,new TimerListener2());`

but fires it at different initial times (by pressing a button). My goal is to add synchronization inside the event handlers so that the one whose timer finished first should wait for the other. Here is a sample code that shows what I mean.

```
private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {                  
            ta_chat.append("here 1\n");
            try {
                barrier1.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(server_frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(server_frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } 
            ta_chat.append("here 2\n");
            ...
         }
     }
```

Same code with TimerListener2.The barrier is initialized in main method

```
final CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
```

and each thread refers to it.

According to [Timer documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

> Although all Timers perform their waiting using a single, shared
>   thread (created by the first Timer object that executes), the action
>   event handlers for Timers execute on another thread -- the
>   event-dispatching thread. This means that the action handlers for
>   Timers can safely perform operations on Swing components. However, it
>   also means that the handlers must execute quickly to keep the GUI
>   responsive.

If I understand correct the handlers are going to run serialized in one thread and the above code will result to a dedlock. When I test the above code the whole gui system freezes. 
My question is if there is a way to overcome this problem, or if there is an alternative way to achieve the goal I described.

Comment: Not using Swing Timers, they will notify the ActionListener from within the EDT, so doing any kind of lockng will prevent you from ever been notified of the second timer. Maybe use a a SwingWorker?

Comment: Oh, also "thread=="t1"" is not how String comparison works in Java

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer for your comment. I just did a small research about SwingWorkers. So if I understand correct in order to create a timer with SwingWorker I need two methods.A doInBackround method that will excecute a `thread.sleep(time)` command and a done() method that will have all the commands the Timmerlistener has?

Comment: I tried to create a Timer using SwingWorkers but it freezes again. It would be really helpfull if someone could illustrate an example how to use SwingWorker to make a timer that accepts CyclicBarrier synchronization. Should I make it a new question?

Comment: [No](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).